# Docker desktop fails to start after windows update

Tags: wsl2, docker-for-windows

Windows 10
Edition Windows 10 Enterprise
Version 22H2
Installed on    ‎7/‎20/‎2022
OS build    19045.2728
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4190.0

Docker was working fine this morning.  IT pushed a windows update, now desktop won't start.  WSL2 is up and running.   This is the error dump.

```
Docker.Core.HttpBadResponseException:
{"message":"1 error occurred:\n\t* starting WSL integration service: synchronising agents: starting added distros: 1 error occurred:\n\t* waiting for WSL integration for Ubuntu-20.04: timed out while polling for WSL distro integration to become ready in \"Ubuntu-20.04\"\n\n\n\n"}

   at Docker.Core.GoBackend.GoBackendClient.<PostNoBodyWithError>d__19.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\4.16.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\GoBackend\GoBackendClient.cs:line 226
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Engines.WSL2.LinuxWSL2Engine.<DoStartAsync>d__11.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\4.16.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\WSL2\LinuxWSL2Engine.cs:line 54
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.TaskExtensions.<WrapAsyncInCancellationException>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\4.16.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\TaskExtensions.cs:line 29
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__6.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\4.16.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 91
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__6.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\4.16.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 118
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.EngineStateMachine.<StartAsync>d__15.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\4.16.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\EngineStateMachine.cs:line 72
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Engines.Engines.<StartAsync>d__23.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\4.16.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\Engines.cs:line 109
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75384185/docker-not-starting-up-after-installation

Comment: post output of "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\com.docker.diagnose.exe"

Comment: Shutdown WSL with `wsl --shutdown` then run `wsl --update`, any substantial updates, should be in the form of an [edit] to your question instead of submitting a comment. The output of `com.docker.diagnose.exe` is mandatory to help you with this problem

Comment: You need to start by talking to IT. They pushed the update, that means they control the system and are responsible for your system meeting your WORK needs.